# How to duplicate full word by partial match in sed

Tags: regex, sed, sh

I have a file in which each line has the following format:

```
foo         tc_TESTNAME,  // TEST #1
```

I would like to duplicate `tc_TESTNAME` in each line as follows:

```
foo         tc_TESTNAME tc_TESTNAME,  // TEST #1
```

Following sed command only duplicates the matching part of the word:

```
# sed -e "s/(tc_*)/& &/"
foo         tc_ tc_TESTNAME,  // TEST #1
```

What is the correct regex syntax to duplicate the whole word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `sed` program.

```bash
sed -E 's/(tc_[^,]+)/\1 \1/' Input_file
```

***OR:*** to match exact word starting from `tc` just in case you may have other strings then make sure space is present in regex like:

```bash
sed -E 's/ (tc_[^,]+)/ \1 \1/'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `-E` option to enable ERE(extended regular expression) and in main program using `s` option to perform substitution. Then matching `(tc_[^,]+)` which captures from tc_ just before next comma comes and capturing this value into 1 capturing group. While substituting it substitute it with itself space and itself as per required output.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the correct regex syntax to duplicate the whole word?

You attempted this sed:

```bash
sed -e "s/(tc_*)/& &/"
```

Which will only duplicate `tc` followed by 0 or more underscores. However what you want to match is `tc_` followed by anything till next comma or whitespace.

With that in mind, following sed should work for you:

```bash
s='foo         tc_TESTNAME,  // TEST #1'
sed 's/tc_[^[:blank:],]*/& &/g' <<< "$s"

foo         tc_TESTNAME tc_TESTNAME,  // TEST #1
```

`[^[:blank:],]*` matches 0 or more of any character that is not a whitespace and not a comma.

Note that there is no need to use extended regex mode for this sed command.